# MapStruct Converter with Autowired Dependency Does Not Work With Mockito

Tags: junit, mockito, mapstruct

Given the following mapper...

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class MyConverter {

    @Autowired protected TimeUtils timeUtils;

    @Mapping(
        target = "expiryDate",
          expression =
              "java(timeUtils.toDate("subscription.getDuration()))")
    public abstract SubscriptionPo convert @NonNull final Subscription subscription);
}
```

... I've defined a mapping that gets the ISO 8601 duration (i.e. "P2Y") from the input `subscription` and calculates the end date by calling `timeUtils.toDate`:

```
public class TimeUtils {

    private final Clock clock = Clock.systemDefaultZone();

    public LocalDate toDate(@NonNull final String iso8601) {
        final Period period = Period.parse(iso8601);
        return (LocalDate) period.addTo(LocalDate.now(clock));
    }
}
```

Then, here is my unit test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyConverteTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyConverter myConverter = Mappers.getMapper(MyConverte.class);

    @Mock private final TimeUtils timeUtils;

    @Test
    void convertPeriodToDate_ok() {
        // setup data
        final Subscription subscription = Subscription.Builder
            .id(1)
            .period("P2Y")
            .build;
  
         final LocalDate expiryDate = new TimeUtils.toDate(subscription.getDuration());

         // commenting out the following line has no effect
         when(timeUtils.toDate(anyString()).thenReturn(expiryDate);

         // run unit test
         final SubscriptionPo subscriptionPo = myConverter.convert(subscription);

         // check result
         assertNotNull(subscriptionPo);
         assertEquals(subscription.getId(), subscriptionPo.getId());             
         assertEquals(expiryDate, subscriptionPo.getExpiryDate());
    }
}
```

When I run the unit test above, it seems that `TimeUtils.toDate`has no effects, i.e. `subscriptionPo.getExpiryDate()` returns `null`. Note that if I use `MyConverter` in the actual code, it works as expected.

Am I missing something? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You shadowed your `timeUtils` mock with this line:

```
final TimeUtils timeUtils = new TimeUtils();
```

A good IDE should mark the mock as not used (IntelliJ does).

A few ideas to fix:

- simple rename would of the local variable will do
- you could extract the getting the variable to method
- I would advise getting rid of mocks altogether in this test.

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyConverterTest {

    private final TimeUtils timeUtils = new TimeUtils();

    private final MyConverter myConverter = buildConverter(timeUtils);

    static MyConverter buildConverter(TimeUtils timeUtils) {
        MyConverter ret = Mappers.getMapper(MyConverter.class);
        ret.timeUtils = timeUtils;
        return ret;
    }

    @Test
    void convertPeriodToDate_ok() {
        // setup data
        final Subscription subscription = new Subscription.Builder()
                .id(1)
                .period("P1Y2M3D")
                .build();

        final LocalDate expiryDate = timeUtils.toDate(subscription.getDuration());

        // run unit test
        final SubscriptionPo subscriptionPo = myConverter.convert(subscription);

        // check result
        assertNotNull(subscriptionPo);
        assertEquals(subscription.getId(), subscriptionPo.getId());
        assertEquals(expiryDate, subscriptionPo.getExpiryDate());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this was an error introduced when I simplified the original code for this post. Just fixed.

Comment: @j3d Please post simplified, but working code. `@Mock private final TimeUtils timeUtils;` does not compile. After fixing the local variable, the test is green for me, and commenting out the stubbing makes it red.

Comment: You're right and I'm sorry... the line should have been '@Mock private TimeUtils timeUtils;' (without 'final'). Then it does compile. Anyway I'll try your proposal. Thanks again :-)